# Insufficient Privileges

Tags: apex

I am getting error Insufficient Privileges when I try to call a method when I click on button click. I am have loged a admin. But I am getting this error. All the field have access to this profile. My anyone let me know what all the reason for this error.

Comment: Do you have access to that apex class? or VisualForce page

Comment: yes I am able to see the VF page and able to get the records from apex class and display the records on the VF page on load but issue comes when I click on next button.

Comment: what is associated to the `Next` button ?  a different VF page?  Or what?  Please provide more details

Comment: There are 2 output panal. By clicking on the next button it hide the first one and display the 2 one.